# No network > local system has static IP(from LAN) but my virtual box(centOS) has no net work

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos, wired-networking

I have installed VirtualBox(centOS 7) on my local system(windows 10).

Local system >> Static IP (from my local Internet Service Provider) VirtualBox Network Settings >> Bridged Adapter with Promiscuous mode open with Allows ALL [VirtualBox Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po2Ul.png)

and for my virtual CentOS 7 network configuration, I put in same as my local system's static IP[My CentOS7 Virtual Box IPConfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSlhx.png)

Kindly let me know that what should be my virtualBox IpConfig sothat i can access internet from my virtualbox ?

Comment: You cannot put the same static IP on bridge mode. That will be a conflict of IP on the same network. Why not use NAT mode? NAT means your CentOS is not visible on the outside world but can still access internet. Unless you need your CentOS visible to the outside world as if it is its own machine?

Answer (score 2):

If your host has a static IP, there's probably a reason.  One likely reason is that you don't have DHCP on your network.  You have two choices:

1. Assign a *different* static IP address (but in the same subnet as your host) on your guest.
2. Use NAT networking in Virtualbox so that your guest will get an address from there.

Normally I really like Bridged networking and I use it the vast majority of the time.  However,  if you're not in control of the network that your host is on, it might not be wise to put other devices on it.  So in your case, I think option 2 is better.

Comment: IF I would like to go for a Bridged network, then what should I have to do here ?

Comment: Since your IP address (on your host) is from your local ISP, you'd have to work with them.  Tell then you want to put another device on the network and get an IP address from them.  Then you can assign it to your CentOS guest.